# How to identify a process for an assembly?

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, process, .net-assembly

I have different assemblies and different processes each process will load few of assemblies from my bin.
How do can we find which assembly belongs to which process?

Comment: Do you want to do this from a code within the assembly or from the outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

use this  System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id

if your exe's are windows forms put that process id in the window.Text

if your exe's are console apps put it in the console

You can find the process from task manager. Process Id column in task manager is not enabled by default so you can do by View Menu->Select Column

Select PID (Process Identifier) and press OK.Now process Id will appear in task manager and in task manger go to processes tab where you can find out exe is linked with what process

Also in Visual studio if you goto Debug -> Attach to process it lists out the process ID's

Comment: I have the problem of identifying process while attaching........Process to IDE to debug.Hope U understood.Suppose I have 5 processes created for my application.I need to identify which assembly belongs to which process.

Comment: You can uniquely identity a process by processID but I am not totally following you can you explain more ?

Comment: I have five different projects in a solution each project is assosiated with one .exe.How do I identify which .exe belongs to which project while attaching the process to debug or before attaching the process.I dont want with code I want from outside.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to split your project out into different solutions. Is that possible ?

Comment: Solution Updated - I think this will get you what you need